# Open Source Agile Project tracker?

Tags: agile, tools, pm-software, open-source

I have a small project I want to carry out.

I need an open source Project Tracker which could integrate with Subversion and has a Scrum oriented UI.

I'm trying to raise this as a client server on a windows server or similar.

There is probably more than one.

Is there any with this characteristics?

Resuming:

- Decent Project tracking
- Scrum oriented UI
- Open Source (or useful as Free version)
- SVN integration
- Liftable on a win based server.
- *Bugtrackers and Project Trackers aren't the same, Project Trackers could contain a Bugtracker...*

Comment: read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774

Comment: Similar:  http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/974/open-source-project-management-software, http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/63/what-are-the-current-tools-available-for-pm, http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/955/project-management-software-for-a-web-development-company

Comment: Software recommendations...

Answer (score 3):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is an obvious choice. We provide its "cloud" installation in [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com) for free, together with Subversion.

Comment: Does it provide any kind of agile methodologies synergy?

Comment: What is "agile methodologies synergy"? Could you please elaborate the term?

Comment: I mean, User stories, the "How do you test it" on each task, a Burndown chart, values from the poker planning, etc... Are those stuff handled by trac?, are those *pluginable* to trac?

Comment: I never used them, but this is the list of plugins available for Trac: http://trac-hacks.org/. I think that you will be able to find most of these features there.

Comment: I've been using it a bit, is good, one of the best on the net. But not as *agile* as was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/). The open source version of the project is free to use and hosted on their site.

- Decent Project tracking - Great UI, burn down charts, iterations, and icebox ready out of box
- Scrum oriented UI - Check
- Open Source (or useful as Free version) - Check
- SVN integration - not sure about this one. I know there is a git integration and their are callback URLs as well.
- Liftable on a win based server - well, you wouldn't have to host it, so this might work out for you.
- Bugtrackers and Project Trackers aren't the same, Project Trackers could contain a Bugtracker - has bug tracking capabilities as they're handled in SCRUM, make a new task for them and associate them with previously created stories

Comment: I've tried it. It is very visual but has no integration or whatsoever with SVN.

Comment: are you consider using git? I would recommend it for an open source project. Git hub is a great resource and has a large community of support. You'll probably get some help with your project more quickly than your own hosted version of the code.

Comment: Pivotal Tracker is not open source, and there appears to be no open source version hosted on their web site. Do you mean that it is offered as a service for no charge to open source projects?

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend [Agilefant](http://www.agilefant.org/wiki/display/AEF/Features). We use it for scrum at our company, and so far it has worked great. It is web based, and can easily be installed on a internal server. It is MIT licensed. It was developed based on research made by the Aalto University's Software Process Research Group.

Comment: +1 — the first answer to actually suggest an open source product focused on agile project management.

Answer (score 1):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) works too. It has built-in calendar, gantt chart, wiki, news, files, documents modules that you can take advantage of. It integrates well with version control systems such as git, Subversion, CVS, etc. This is free.

Comment: Is it scrum oriented?

Comment: Is it a project tracker or a bug tracker?

Comment: @apacay, yes to all questions

Comment: and... Has any agile methodologies integration? User stories, the "How do you test it" on each task, a Burndown chart, values from the poker planning, etc... Are those stuff handled by Redmine?, are those *pluginable* to Redmine?

Comment: Redmine plugin to add some agile tools: http://www.redminebacklogs.net/

Answer (score 1):

[]project-open[](http://www.project-open.com/) is open-source and includes both [SCRUM and agile methodologies](http://www.project-open.org/en/howto_scrum_project_management) as well as an SVN integration. Installers are available for Win* and Linux. It's a pretty big system though, so it might take some time to set it up.

Affiliation: Please note that I'm a member of the ]po[ team.

Comment: Interesting. How do you pronounce `]po[`?

Comment: ]po[ is "project open" :-) Sorry for the shameless self promotion, but had little else to add...

Answer (score 0):

I used TFS for quite some time and enjoyed its integration with source control.  However, it is not open source...and it has almost lead me to a different direction.  Although the concept of tying SCC to the task tracking, it almost became more of a chore for the development team.

I started to wonder what benefits I was actually getting from tying the source control to the reporting utility, etc.?  What are your main goals for this integration?  Is it just one interface *IDE* that everyone can use?

I really like using tools like RallyDev (free up to a certain size team) and VersionOne...basically easy to use interfaces that have a pretty strong community behind them.   I know it isn't what you requested, but wanted to:

1) Understand your needs to SCC integration and 
2) Provide you with a couple of other options that might work for a smaller team for free (RallyDev)

Answer (score -2):

Recommend Microsoft Project 2010. It includes an interactive module to help effectively visualize and manage resources. Microsoft Project 2010 improves productivity through a simple and intuitive user experience and enhances collaboration and reporting. Although it is not free but you can get a free 60-day trial for evaluation. I will recommend you to try [Project Management Standard](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/project-standard-2010.aspx) 2010 to see how it fits your needs.

Comment: certainly this isn't what I was looking for. Has no integration with code versioning, and I didn't see any agile plugin to it. Is there any? Is it good enough to pay for it?

Comment: Original poster asked for "open source" tool; evaluation periods don't qualify as "open source" :)